# what does greenthread.sleep do?

Tags: eventlet

I'm pretty new with eventlet and have some questions on sleep()

I tested with a small piece of code.

At first I spawned 3 greenthreads and then called greenthread.sleep(0), then these 3 greenthreads all came to execute the functions in them. what's going on?

does sleep() mean execute all the greenthread spawned? what does the argument 0 we passed in mean?

Here is the code:

```
import eventlet
from eventlet import greenthread
from eventlet import event
evt = event.Event()

def func1():
    print "starting func1"
    evt.wait()
    print "stopping func1"

def func2():
    print "starting func2"
    evt.wait()
    print "stopping func2"

def func3():
    evt.send()

gt1 = greenthread.spawn(func1)
gt2 = greenthread.spawn(func2)
gt3 = greenthread.spawn(func3)
greenthread.sleep(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question, it deserves a special place in Eventlet documentation.

`eventlet.sleep(0)` reschedules the calling greenthread to the end of run queue. If there were any other greenthreads waiting to run, they will execute now.

Current implementation detail of Eventlet has a certain guarantee that if you call sleep, the calling greenthread will not continue until all other greenthreads *that are ready to execute* are finished or came to similar wait state. Started as implementation detail, we keep it as a public API now: call `sleep(0)` to let others run.